# Automatically refresh auth token in aiohttp

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, aiohttp

I'm using aiohttp for a long-running process. At the beginning I authorize with the API get back an access token. The response also includes a refresh_token value (I think it's using oauth2).

The process I'm running takes over an hour and the access token expires after 60 minutes (as indicated by the `expires_in` value of 3600 in the auth response. I think I can refresh the authorization using the `refresh_token` but would ideally like to configure the client session to automatically refresh as needed.

I'm thinking that it should either:

- Automatically refresh the tokens as soon as one of the responses returns a 401 code and then retry
- Automatically refresh the token after a specified amount of time (e.g. 3500 seconds)

Is there a recommended way to subclass `ClientSession` for `aiohttp`. [I found this one example](https://gist.github.com/kellerza/5ca798f49983bb702bc6e7a05ba53def) but don't quite follow it.